# Cambiar el título de un terminal mediante script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, fedora

puesto que trabajo con varios terminales a la vez y por circustancias, muchos de ellos tienen un prompt muy parecido, me interesaría que cada uno de los terminales tuvieran un título mas descriptivo y facil de leer para mi. Se que desde las opciones se puede hacer de manera sencilla, pero me gustaría hacerlo a través de un script (que por otra parte sería automático y mas limpio)

Por el momento, he probado varias cosas que he ido encontrando:

```
echo -en '\033]0;20.11\a'

echo -ne "\033]0;TITULO AQUI\007"

echo -e '\033]2;TITULO AQUI\007'

gnome-terminal --title="TITULO AQUI"
```

Nada de ésto cambia el título de la consola, ni siquiera cuando abro una nueva terminal. Yo me supongo que es algo del `PROMPT_COMMAND` en `/etc/bashrc`, pero no tengo muy claro como dejarlo en un script o para una conexión SSH.

Answer (score 3):

Encontré el modo.

Hay que definir el `PROMPT_COMMAND` con un `echo`, como el que había puesto al principio de mi pregunta:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -en "\033]0;PRUEBA\a"'
```

Así se establece el título del terminal en la consola y el Terminal gnome-terminal.